# Odd characters in string output C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I keep getting this odd problem where these characters appear in my char array called `day[3]`. My goal is to use the computers clock and get the date and time. I put that into a string called dayHolder and want to just add the day it to a char array called `day`. But when I do this it gets a lot of odd characters. I understand that the string should end with '\0' but cant seem to get `day` to just display "Fri"....

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Functions
    functions myFunc;

    //Variables + installations  
    string dayHolder;
    char day[3];
    char whitespace = ' ';
    time_t current = time(0);

    dayHolder = ctime(&current);


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        day[i] = dayHolder[i];
    }



    cout << ctime(&current) << endl;
    cout << dayHolder << endl;
    cout << day << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

[image]

So what can I do to fix this problem? I am sure its something simple that I am overlooking so any advise or suggestions would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You're missing the null terminator on the string.

Comment: Since you understand that string must be null terminated. Then why you don't `char day[4] ... day[3] = '\0';`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char day[3]` is not zero-terminated.

Try

```
char day[4];

....

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    day[i] = dayHolder[i];
}
day[3] = 0; // or '\0' as @DeepBlackDwarf suggested
```

Or, alternatively

```
string day = dayHolder.substr(0, 3);
```

Comment: Hey, wow that worked! I am going to look it up after I post this but I thought that char arrays start at base 0. So in the case of Fri 0 = F, 1 = r, 2 = i, 3 = null i.e \0. Is how does making the memory of the array 4 fix this?

Comment: There is no `3`. `day[3]` declares an array or three elements, with indices `0`, `1`, `2`. In addition, array is not initialized by default (but see the answer of **fbrereto**).

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an extra `'\0'` character at the end of the string, ie declare a `char day[4]` and assign the last char with `day[3] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to null-terminate, as has been mentioned. First you'll need to add another byte for the null. Another option is to zero out the buffer initially:

```
char day[4] = { 0 };
```

As long as you don't overwrite `day[3]` that value will stay `0` and the string will stay a valid c-string.

Comment: Except that they write 3 characters in, so unless the buffer is larger you still won't have a terminating null character.

Comment: One more for the null terminator: `char day[4] = { 0 }`

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `cout` keeps on writing to stdout until it meets a null terminator, hence the garbage values. Since you are using a C-style string, you should always remember to include an additional space in order to null terminate your string (e.g. you want to store 3 chars, so buffer should have size of 4). Others already mentioned that you need a bigger buffer and put there a `\0` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `std::string` since you've already included `string` header:

```
time_t current = time(0);
string dayHolder = ctime(&current);
string day(dayHolder.begin(), dayHolder.begin() + 3);
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c8180a42dffe4aa)